# No module name seaborn with django

Tags: python, django, matplotlib, seaborn

I am using Anaconda distribution for python and I have selected anaconda as a python interpreter for pycharm idea . I have installed seaborn and its recommended packages through anaconda. Those packages are installed within anaconda not within my core python lib

I have also use the bellow code and run my program through command line and it works well.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

The problem is when I use this same code within django in pycharm I have got run time error "No module name seaborn" but there is no compile time error, I can import the packages through code completion

so when I run my django project It throughs the error

```
 File "H:\py\mysite\myapp\views.py", line 10, in module
 import seaborn as sns
 ImportError: No module named 'seaborn'
```

what is the problem and how can I solve this

Comment: Are you using the same virtual env/python interpreter in pycharm as you do in your console?

Comment: I am not using any virtual environment, I am using default environment that is provided by django, and the itepreter is Anaconda/python

Comment: Do you have multiple Python versions installed?